# What does "Set an Input handler" mean in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, when configuring an external tool (Run->External Tools->External Tools Configurations...), specifically an Ant Build, under the Main tab there is a checkbox labeled "Set an Input Handler".  This is checked by default.

What does this do?  When would you want to uncheck it and what would the benefits be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is when you are using the **[`input` Ant Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/input.html)**, which can need an [**`InputHandler`**](http://ant.apache.org/manual/inputhandler.html).

> When a task wants to prompt a user for input, **it doesn't simply read the input from the console as this would make it impossible to embed Ant in an IDE**.
>   Instead it asks an implementation of the `org.apache.tools.ant.input.InputHandler` interface to prompt the user and hand the user input back to the task.

Comment: @martin: thank you for all your updates around old Ant documentation links ;)

Comment: sorry to keep disturbing you - I'm sure there will be one or two more.

Comment: @martin: "disturbing"? Not at all. This is a great service to the SO community (as well as to some of my answers ;) ). Plus this Gold "Copy Editor" shall be yours in no time (and well deserved too).